# Cannot boot to Windows after installing Ubuntu and running boot-repair

Tags: grub2, windows-7, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on to a 2nd drive (sbd2) whilst the first driver (sbda) has Windows 7. When I rebooted I was not given the grub bootloader and booted straight to Ubuntu.

After running boot-repair, I now get the GRUB boot loader but with no Windows option.

Here is the output from boot-repair:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6726912/

Please can you help me to restore the option of booting to Windows 7.

I can see my windows install NTFS partition mounted in Ubunutu

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by posting the log from boot-repair on [this forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769482).
The part of [this answer](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1769482&page=171&p=12896854#post12896854) that worked for me was

> uncheck the default and in advanced choose the Windows install and sda